# Getting unrecognized authentication type error with node.js nodemailer module

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am trying to connect to a microsoft mail server, with node.js nodemailer module. But I get an error.

```
// create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'mysmtp.server.com',
    port: 25,
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
    requireTLS: true,
    ignoreTLS: false,
    tls : {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    },
    authMethod: 'LOGIN',
    auth: {
        type: 'login',
        user: 'account@domain.com', // generated ethereal user
        pass: 'password'  // generated ethereal password
    }
});

transporter.verify(function(error, success) {
    if (error) {
         console.log(error);
    } else {
         console.log('Server is ready to take our messages');
    }
 });
```

ERROR:

```
{ Error: Invalid login: 504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (C:\Users\user\Desktop\mail\node_modules\
nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:577:19)
    at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (C:\Users\user\Desktop\mail\node_m
odules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1306:34)
    at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str (C:\Users\user\Desktop\mail\
node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:349:26)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (C:\Users\user\Desktop\mail\node_modu
les\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:733:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (C:\Users\user\Desktop\mail\node_modules\nodem
ailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:529:14)
    at TLSSocket._socket.on.chunk (C:\Users\user\Desktop\mail\node_modules\n
odemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:680:51)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
  code: 'EAUTH',
  response: '504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type',
  responseCode: 504,
  command: 'AUTH PLAIN' }
```

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Thanks